# Dragging formulas across - Increment columns by more than 1

Tags: excel, formula, increment, drag

I can't seem to find anything similar that's already been asked (they all relate to incrementing row numbers rather than columns)

I'm looking to drag a formula across horizontally and have the columns increment by 2

E.g. B1-A1, D1-C1, F1-E1...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a value in cell A1 and B1 for the following to work.

For my testing I put the number 1 in A1 and B1.

Try this in Cell C1:

`=IF(MOD(COUNT($A$1:B1),2)=0,COLUMN(B1),IF(B1<>A1,B1,A1))`

Here's what you should see when you drag that formula across:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K  L  M  N
1 1 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10 10 12 12
```

**And this is what the formula does:**

- The `MOD(COUNT()` part of the formula counts the cells to the left of it, and if they are a multiple of 2, the value changes.
- I've left the value to change to (the 'new' value) as the `COLUMN()` number for the cell before, just for example's sake. but you can change this part.
- The last `IF` statement at the end checks if the cell before is equal to the cell before that, (eg. Is `CELL C1` equal to `CELL B1`) and if they are not equal, it will give the cell before as a value (the 'copy' value).